# How to stop java mail from opening so many connections

Tags: java, email, while-loop, jakarta-mail

I'm creating software to control my lights with a relay it talks to my raspberry pi via SSH but to get control from anywhere I made it so this java code checks my email every 1 second to see if the command is there `+myRoom`, `-myRoom` the issue I'm having is that even though I close the connection and reopen it, it still says `java.io.EOFException: [SYS/TEMP] Maximum number of connections from user+IP exceeded (mail_max_userip_connections=5)` I know this is both a server and code issue because it can be resolved by just not adding a limit to the connections but this is a shared server and that would give possible downtime on them. Now as you can see in my code I've tried closing the connection, then waiting 1 sec and reconnecting but after the 5th go I get that error. Is there a way around this?

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javax.mail.Folder;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Store;


public class GetEmails {

    public static void on() throws IOException {
        String command = "python on.py";

        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

        // deal with OutputStream to send inputs
        process.getOutputStream();

        // deal with InputStream to get ordinary outputs
        process.getInputStream();

        // deal with ErrorStream to get error outputs
        process.getErrorStream();
    }

    public static void off() throws IOException{
        String command = "python off.py";

        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

        // deal with OutputStream to send inputs
        process.getOutputStream();

        // deal with InputStream to get ordinary outputs
        process.getInputStream();

        // deal with ErrorStream to get error outputs
        process.getErrorStream();
    }

    public static void check(String host, String storeType, String user,
                             String password)
    {
        try {

            //create properties field
            Properties properties = new Properties();

            properties.put("mail.pop3.host", host);
            properties.put("mail.pop3.port", "995");
            properties.put("mail.pop3.starttls.enable", "true");

            Session emailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

            //create the POP3 store object and connect with the pop server
            Store store = emailSession.getStore("pop3s");

            store.connect(host, user, password);

            boolean power = true;
            while(true){



                //create the folder object and open it
                Folder emailFolder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
                emailFolder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

                // retrieve the messages from the folder in an array
                Message[] messages = emailFolder.getMessages();

                int i = messages.length - 1;
                Message message = messages[i];
                String subject = message.getSubject();

//                System.out.println(subject);
                if(subject.equals("+myRoom") && power == false){
                    System.out.println("Light on");
//                    on();
                    power = true;
                    System.out.println("done");
                }
                else if (subject.equals("-myRoom") && power == true){
                    System.out.println("Light Off");
//                    off();
                    power = false;
                    System.out.println("done");

                }
                else{
                    continue;
                }
                //store.close();
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
                //store.connect(host, user, password);
            }


        } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String host = "EMAIL SERVER";// change accordingly
        String mailStoreType = "pop3";
        String username = "EMAIL";// change accordingly
        String password = "PASSWORD";// change accordingly

        check(host, mailStoreType, username, password);

    }

}
```

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant to the question, but just calling 'process.getOutputStream()', for example, does not 'deal with' anything.  It gets you a reference to a stream which you're then supposed to use to read the output.

Comment: oh ok thanks @iggy

Comment: The obvious solution is to stop calling `connect` in the loop

Comment: @g00se nope still dont work

Comment: You be wise to have a boolean variable rather than a literal in `while` and every second is far too frequent for POP mail. I would call `close` on the `Store` in a `finally` block.
Your server might take a while to recover from the assault it's been under - tantamount to a DOS attack ;)

Comment: @g00se thanks but do you know how to fix the issue

Comment: As i said, you might have to wait a while. Also make that sleep 15 seconds